# AEM listen to bundle registration

Tags: aem

I know I can use a JCR EventListener to check things like changes on nodes. I also know OSGi bundles implement a ServiceListener interface which let them know when a bundle is registered or stopped.

I think I'm somewhat close but I can't seem to connect the dots. How in AEM can I deploy a bundle that can listen to other bundles ServiceEvent changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can listen to OSGi events, using Felix EventAdmin.

[There](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html) you can find specification but in a couple of words:

1. First you need to implement interface EventHandler
2. Register your handler for events with topic **org/osgi/framework/BundleEvent/STARTED**

In documentation they do not use annotations, but if you use maven scr plugin in you project - you can do it with annotations. Your code could look like:

```
@Component
@Service(value = EventHandler.class)
@Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value = { ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC })
public class YourEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // do smth with event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case? do you need a [BundleTracker](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTracker.html) or a [ServiceTracker](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html).

As may be the case you may need to extend BundleTracker/ServiceTracker and handle your logic in addingxxxxxx/ modifiedxxxxxx/ removedxxxxxx methods.

Some examples you can check [AEM commons code](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/wcm/impl/CustomPollingImporterListServlet.java) and [Tracker](http://www.aqute.biz/Snippets/Tracker)